# How do I pass multiple clips to animation-mixer

Tags: animation, three.js, aframe, ar.js, 8thwall-xr

I just wanted to know, how do I pass multiple clips to animation-mixer?

The extension GitHub mentions that the clip parameter accepts clips(s). I have tried to add multiple clip names separated by comma and in array, but nothing works. How does it work?

```
    model.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
      clip: '["Idle", "Laugh"]',
      loop: 'once',
      crossFadeDuration: 0.4,
      timeScale: 1,
    })
```

Comment: how about chaining them one after another?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I wanted the specified animations to play simultaneously, rather than one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation-mixer component does not support multiple animation names. However, if you use the asterisk(*) at the end of the word. Then, it will generate a Regexp that will match every clip that starts with the word before the * and everything after it.

E.g.

Idle* will be converted into ^Idle.*$ Regexp, therefore, any clip that starts with word "Idle" will be matched.

Comment: A PR that will allow use of arbitrary regular expressions for the `clip` property.  https://github.com/c-frame/aframe-extras/pull/421.

So you could do: `clip:Idle|Laugh`